# NodeJS ssh2 fastGet hangs on decompression

Tags: node.js, ssh, sftp, freeze, compression

Using the nodejs ssh2 library by mscdex, I have a sftp "fetch" node script that will list the contents of an ssh server directory, searches for particular files, and then downloads them. When the script gets to the download step where it calls "sftp.fastGet", the callback provided to fastGet is never called.

I've turned on the "DEBUG" setting in the ssh connection option. It seems like the sftp.fastGet is executing, but is hanging on a "decompress" step. This is the output I am getting:

```
...
DEBUG: Parser: Verifying MAC
DEBUG: Parser: IN_PACKETDATAVERIFY (Valid HMAC)
DEBUG: Parser: Decompressing
// hangs here forever (or until timeout)...
```

What is more strange, several packets seem to come over and decompress correctly. Here is the (more verbose) debug:

```
info: Fetching xxx from /xxx/xxx/xxx to X:\xxx\xxx\xxx
debug: DEBUG[SFTP]: Outgoing: Writing OPEN
debug: DEBUG: Outgoing: Writing CHANNEL_DATA (0)
debug: DEBUG: Parser: IN_PACKET
debug: DEBUG: Parser: Decrypting
debug: DEBUG: Parser: pktLen:20,padLen:5,remainLen:16
debug: DEBUG: Parser: IN_PACKETDATA
debug: DEBUG: Parser: Decrypting
debug: DEBUG: Parser: HMAC size:20
debug: DEBUG: Parser: IN_PACKETDATAVERIFY
debug: DEBUG: Parser: Verifying MAC
debug: DEBUG: Parser: IN_PACKETDATAVERIFY (Valid HMAC)
debug: DEBUG: Parser: Decompressing
// doesn't seem to hang here
debug: DEBUG: Parser: IN_PACKETDATAAFTER, packet: CHANNEL_DATA (0)
debug: DEBUG[SFTP]: Parser: Response: HANDLE
debug: DEBUG[SFTP]: Outgoing: Writing FSTAT
debug: DEBUG: Outgoing: Writing CHANNEL_DATA (0)
debug: DEBUG: Parser: IN_PACKETBEFORE (expecting 8)
debug: DEBUG: Parser: IN_PACKET
debug: DEBUG: Parser: Decrypting
debug: DEBUG: Parser: pktLen:28,padLen:10,remainLen:24
debug: DEBUG: Parser: IN_PACKETDATA
debug: DEBUG: Parser: Decrypting
debug: DEBUG: Parser: HMAC size:20
debug: DEBUG: Parser: IN_PACKETDATAVERIFY
debug: DEBUG: Parser: Verifying MAC
debug: DEBUG: Parser: IN_PACKETDATAVERIFY (Valid HMAC)
debug: DEBUG: Parser: Decompressing
// doesn't seem to hang here
debug: DEBUG: Parser: IN_PACKETDATAAFTER, packet: CHANNEL_DATA (0)
debug: DEBUG[SFTP]: Parser: Response: ATTRS
debug: DEBUG: Parser: IN_PACKETBEFORE (expecting 8)
debug: DEBUG[SFTP]: Outgoing: Writing READ
debug: DEBUG: Outgoing: Writing CHANNEL_DATA (0)
debug: DEBUG[SFTP]: Outgoing: Writing READ
debug: DEBUG: Outgoing: Writing CHANNEL_DATA (0)
debug: DEBUG[SFTP]: Outgoing: Writing READ
debug: DEBUG: Outgoing: Writing CHANNEL_DATA (0)
debug: DEBUG[SFTP]: Outgoing: Writing READ
debug: DEBUG: Outgoing: Writing CHANNEL_DATA (0)
debug: DEBUG[SFTP]: Outgoing: Writing READ
debug: DEBUG: Outgoing: Writing CHANNEL_DATA (0)
debug: DEBUG[SFTP]: Outgoing: Writing READ
debug: DEBUG: Outgoing: Writing CHANNEL_DATA (0)
debug: DEBUG[SFTP]: Outgoing: Writing READ
debug: DEBUG: Outgoing: Writing CHANNEL_DATA (0)
debug: DEBUG[SFTP]: Outgoing: Writing READ
debug: DEBUG: Outgoing: Writing CHANNEL_DATA (0)
debug: DEBUG[SFTP]: Outgoing: Writing READ
debug: DEBUG: Outgoing: Writing CHANNEL_DATA (0)
debug: DEBUG[SFTP]: Outgoing: Writing READ
debug: DEBUG: Outgoing: Writing CHANNEL_DATA (0)
debug: DEBUG[SFTP]: Outgoing: Writing READ
debug: DEBUG: Outgoing: Writing CHANNEL_DATA (0)
debug: DEBUG[SFTP]: Outgoing: Writing READ
debug: DEBUG: Outgoing: Writing CHANNEL_DATA (0)
debug: DEBUG[SFTP]: Outgoing: Writing READ
debug: DEBUG: Outgoing: Writing CHANNEL_DATA (0)
debug: DEBUG[SFTP]: Outgoing: Writing READ
debug: DEBUG: Outgoing: Writing CHANNEL_DATA (0)
debug: DEBUG[SFTP]: Outgoing: Writing READ
debug: DEBUG: Outgoing: Writing CHANNEL_DATA (0)
debug: DEBUG[SFTP]: Outgoing: Writing READ
debug: DEBUG: Outgoing: Writing CHANNEL_DATA (0)
debug: DEBUG[SFTP]: Outgoing: Writing READ
debug: DEBUG: Outgoing: Writing CHANNEL_DATA (0)
debug: DEBUG[SFTP]: Outgoing: Writing READ
debug: DEBUG: Outgoing: Writing CHANNEL_DATA (0)
debug: DEBUG[SFTP]: Outgoing: Writing READ
debug: DEBUG: Outgoing: Writing CHANNEL_DATA (0)
debug: DEBUG[SFTP]: Outgoing: Writing READ
debug: DEBUG: Outgoing: Writing CHANNEL_DATA (0)
debug: DEBUG[SFTP]: Outgoing: Writing READ
debug: DEBUG: Outgoing: Writing CHANNEL_DATA (0)
debug: DEBUG[SFTP]: Outgoing: Writing READ
debug: DEBUG: Outgoing: Writing CHANNEL_DATA (0)
debug: DEBUG[SFTP]: Outgoing: Writing READ
debug: DEBUG: Outgoing: Writing CHANNEL_DATA (0)
debug: DEBUG[SFTP]: Outgoing: Writing READ
debug: DEBUG: Outgoing: Writing CHANNEL_DATA (0)
debug: DEBUG[SFTP]: Outgoing: Writing READ
debug: DEBUG: Outgoing: Writing CHANNEL_DATA (0)
debug: DEBUG: Parser: IN_PACKET
debug: DEBUG: Parser: Decrypting
debug: DEBUG: Parser: pktLen:2388,padLen:6,remainLen:2384
debug: DEBUG: Parser: IN_PACKETDATA
debug: DEBUG: Parser: Decrypting
debug: DEBUG: Parser: HMAC size:20
debug: DEBUG: Parser: IN_PACKETDATAVERIFY
debug: DEBUG: Parser: Verifying MAC
debug: DEBUG: Parser: IN_PACKETDATAVERIFY (Valid HMAC)
debug: DEBUG: Parser: Decompressing
// hangs here forever...
```

I cracked open "[my project]\node_modules\ssh2-streams\lib\ssh.js" and found that the "decompress.instance.flush" method callback was not being called every time.

```
ssh.js line 544: ...
} else if (instate.status === IN_PACKETDATAAFTER) {
  if (decompress.instance) {
  if (!decomp) {
    debug('DEBUG: Parser: Decompressing');
    decompress.instance.write(instate.payload);
    // this function executes and calls the method below
    decompress.instance.flush(Z_PARTIAL_FLUSH, function(){
      // this callback function is called during the first two iterations,
      // but is not called the last time, when the process hangs
      instate.payload = decompress.instance.read();
      var nextSlice;
      if (i === chlen)
        nextSlice = EMPTY_BUFFER;
      else
        nextSlice = chunk.slice(i);
      self._transform(nextSlice, encoding, callback, true);
    });
    return;
  } else {
  ...
```

... and of course, here is the code I am running

```
var sshClient = require('ssh2').Client;

var client = new sshClient();

client.on('ready', ()=> {

  client.sftp( (sftpErr, sftp) => {

    sftp.readdir(remotepath, (dirErr, files) => {

      var validFiles = files.filter( (file) => {
        return file.filename.match(regex);
      });  

      async.eachSeries(validFiles, (ftpFile, cb) => {

        var remote = remotepath + ftpFile.filename;
        var local = path.join(localpath, ftpFile.filename);


        console.log('Fetching ' + ftpFile.filename + ' from ' + remote + ' to ' + local);

        sftp.fastGet(remote, local, (getErr) => {
          console.log('Fast Get Complete');
          // this is never called
        });

      });

    })

  });

});

client.connect({
  host: "xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx",
  port: 22,
  username: "someuser",
  password: "somepass",
  debug: console.log,
  algorithms: {
    key: [
      "diffie-hellman-group1-sha1",
    ],
    cipher: [
      "blowfish-cbc",
      "3des-cbc"
    ],
    compress: [
      "zlib"
    ],
    hmac: [
      "hmac-sha1",
      "hmac-md5"
    ]
  }
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `flush()` callback is only called once all (current) uncompressed data is read from the zlib stream. This was only an issue when the uncompressed data length exceeded the zlib stream's `highWaterMark`. This should now be fixed as of [mscdex/ssh2-streams@8c0906c6b8](https://github.com/mscdex/ssh2-streams/commit/8c0906c6b8bc5f2a98ccef07cac70eb65a32ae20).